# How to make pdfkit (and wkhtmltopdf) work on Google Colab?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, pdfkit, python-pdfkit

I'm using pdfkit with jupyter notebook on windows 10 without problem.

Now I need to use it on Google Colab and don't even know where to start.

I tried installing the linux package into the "/users/contents"

```
! wget "https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-3/wkhtmltox-0.12.6-3.archlinux-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz" && \
tar vxfJ "wkhtmltox-0.12.6-3.archlinux-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz" && \
mv wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

It installed correctly.

I tried to make pdfkit point to the path "/content/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf" but didn't work.

```
!pip install pdfkit
import pdfkit
path_wkhtmltopdf = "/content/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)
pdfkit.from_url("test.html", "out.pdf", configuration=config)
```

The error returned:

```
Collecting pdfkit
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/da/48fdd627794cde49f4ee7854d219f3a65714069b722b8d0e3599cd066185/pdfkit-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pdfkit
Successfully installed pdfkit-0.6.1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-b691bc3e9060> in <module>()
      3 path_wkhtmltopdf = "/content/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
      4 config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)
----> 5 pdfkit.from_url("yggtorrent1.html", "out.pdf", configuration=config)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pdfkit/pdfkit.py in to_pdf(self, path)
    157 
    158         if exit_code != 0:
--> 159             raise IOError("wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code {0}. error:\n{1}".format(exit_code, stderr))
    160 
    161         # Since wkhtmltopdf sends its output to stderr we will capture it

OSError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error:
/content/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /content/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf)
/content/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /content/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

#This worked for me

#First you check your operating system

`!cat /etc/os-release`

#And check and check processor architecture with `!uname -m`

Mine is ( get Ubuntu x86_64)

#Now you install the dependecies

```
!pip install pdfkit

!wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb

!cp wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb /usr/bin

!sudo apt install /usr/bin/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb
```

#pdfkit should work now

`pdfkit.from_url("test.html", "out.pdf")`

source:[How to set wkhtmltoimage path when using imgkit in google colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70893465/how-to-set-wkhtmltoimage-path-when-using-imgkit-in-google-colab)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately, I get
```
Note, selecting 'wkhtmltox' instead of
'/usr/bin/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb' Some packages could not
be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible
situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some
required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of
Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:
 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  wkhtmltox : Depends:
libssl1.1 but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you
have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of the code block (pdfkit + requests) works fine in Google Colab.

```
!pip install pdfkit
!pip install requests

import pdfkit
import requests

# Function to generate a PDF from a URL
def generate_pdf_from_url(url, output_file):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an exception if there's an HTTP error

        # Use pdfkit to generate PDF from HTML content
        pdfkit.from_string(response.text, output_file)
        print("PDF generated successfully!")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("Error fetching URL:", str(e))
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Error generating PDF:", str(ex))

# Example usage:
url = "https://www.example.com"  # Replace with your desired URL
output_file = "output.pdf"  # Output file name

generate_pdf_from_url(url, output_file)
```