# How to set wkhtmltoimage path when using imgkit in google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, imgkit

Im trying to save an html file as an image using imgkit in google colab. Im having trouble making it work.

```
!pip install imgkit
!pip install wkhtmltopdf

import imgkit 
imgkit.from_file('file.html', 'out.jpg')
```

Error:

```
No wkhtmltoimage executable found: "command not found"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it.
Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - http://wkhtmltopdf.org
```

I´ve read I have to set the path manually, but i can´t figure out what the path is. I haven't found answers about making it work in **Google Colab**

Thks!

Edit: I made it work thanks to @user2314737 answer

```
%%bash
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb
```

**After geting the package I had to copy it to /usr/bin:**

```
!cp wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb /usr/bin
!sudo apt install /usr/bin/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb
```

And then just:

```
import imgkit
imgkit.from_file('file.html', 'out.jpg')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the executable. Check your operating system with

```
!cat /etc/os-release
# Out:
# NAME="Ubuntu"
# VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
# ...
```

and check processor architecture with `!uname -m`

(I get Ubuntu x86_64)

Then install the executable with

```
!wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb
!cp wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb /usr/bin
!sudo apt install /usr/bin/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb
```

Here's the list of all downloads: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: Do i need to set a specific path? im getting this error now: OSError: wkhtmltoimage exited with non-zero code 1. error:
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage)
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage)

Comment: @IgnacioBasti corrected the answer with the right version --> Ubuntu 18 Bionic amd64

Answer (score 0):

To install the lib, add:

```
!apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

Run this code to check if everything is setup perfectly

```
import pdfkit

r = pdfkit.PDFKit('html', 'string', verbose=True)
print(' '.join(r.command()))
# try running wkhtmltopdf to create PDF
output = r.to_pdf()
```